# How can I put the link to fan page on canvas page?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I want to add a link to fan page on my canvas page.
I put HTML code normally like below.

```
<a href="*******">go to fanpage</a>
```

I clicked this link on canvas page, then screen shows facebook logo instead of it shows my fan page. Anyway I clicked the facebook logo, then move to my fan page.

How can I make it move to fan page directly?

Comment: What was the value of `href`?

Comment: Its fan page URL. like " http://www.facebook.com/******?v=wall"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break out of the iframe by specifying target:

`<a href="*******" target="_top">go to fanpage</a>`

Comment: I could confirm it.Thank you so much!

Comment: Thankyou. I tried various things, without thinking of the obvious! Its worth mentioning that you may need to consider the http/https issue, as this will become important soon.I have opted for http for the time being.